# ASP.NET TextRenderer.DrawText Awful Text Images

Tags: c#, asp.net

Since I've tried to draw string with every combination of smoothing and rendering with `Graphics.DrawString()` I was thinking that text renderer would do a better job drawing my strings but I think was wrong.

This is how it is supposed to look like:

[image]

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Graphics objGraphics2 = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);

objGraphics2.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
objGraphics2.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
objGraphics2.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
objGraphics2.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

Font textFont = new Font(textFontFamily, PxtoEm(textSize));

SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(textColor);

TextRenderer.DrawText(objGraphics2, textValue, textFont, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), textColor);
```

Is my `PxtoEm` method wrong?

```
public float PxtoEm(int px)
{
      float em = (float)(Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(px) * Convert.ToDouble(72) / Convert.ToDouble(objBitmap.HorizontalResolution)));
      return em;
}
```

I need some suggestions because this is really awful, it gets worse with larger fonts and images aren't shrunk.

**UPDATE: Got it working with bigger fonts(ie. 20px) but with smaller fonts it gets kind of erased on some letters:**

This is how it's suposed to be with font Arial 10px:

[image]

This is result with `Graphics.DrawString()`

[image]

As you can see it really isn't very good but closest I got. I made some changes to code and got better results with larger font:

This is how it's suposed to be with font Arial 20px:

[image]

This is drawing result:

[image]

And here is the changed code(I droped em method and used pixels directly, switched to Graphics.DrawString() instead of TextRenderer.DrawText()

```
  Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmap);
  objGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
  objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
  objGraphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
  objGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
  objGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
  Font textFont = new Font(textFontFamily, textSize,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
  SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(textColor);
  PointF origin = new PointF((float)TextLeft,(float)TextTop);
  StringFormat format = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;

  objGraphics.DrawString(textValue, textFont, b , origin, format);
```

If someone has some suggestion to maybe write different method for smaller text sizes and use above code for larger as it works nicely, post it and I'll try it!

**UPDATE 3: Finally found solution for everything, and solution was rather simple:**
DON'T USE TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND!

And settings are:

```
 objGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
 objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit; // <-- important!
 objGraphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
 objGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
 objGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
          objGraphics.TextContrast = 0;
```

Here is final image with these settings on white background:

[image]

Exactly the same, thanks for suggestions and replies.

Comment: What graphics format are you streaming the image as?

Comment: Format is Png because and background is transparent.I'm Currently trying out all the stuff other suggested below so far nothing changed when using TextRenderer instead I got back to Graphics.DrawString agian and results are a little better. I will post agian when I get right combo.

Comment: Cool, just checking to make sure you weren't trying to use GIF, as that would lose the alpha channel and give you similar ugly results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built something to generate image buttons using similar functionality and I had issues with kerneling and the font not stretching to the desired with.  The following settings got me really close to what I wanted but still not 100%.

```
objGraphics2.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
objGraphics2.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
```

Comment: This is working but only for larger font(ie. 20px), anyway closest I got so far. I'll try to play around some more to see if I could get better result with smaller fonts.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it will help but why not create your font without the function call, like this:

```
 Font textFont = new Font(textFontFamily, textSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: This helped to make it easier but still the same, thanks anyway i overlooked this.

Comment: n.p.  I didn't think it would help with the rendering quality but simpler code is always a :D

Answer (score 2):

Set `Graphics.TextRenderingHint` to `SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve the issue, but I had a similar problem with drawing text in Direct3D, check out [PixelOffsetMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.pixeloffsetmode%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), set it to `Half`.

Comment: I tried, it gets messy with larger fonts and same as HighQuality on smaller.