# graphics.DrawString() not properly rendering

Tags: c#, .net-core, monogame

I'm trying to render some text onscreen in Monogame by drawing a string to a Texture2D

This is the output I currently have

[image: wrong1]

this is what i want it to look like

[image: correct]

and here is a snippet of the code

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(b);

g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);

//Quality settings
g.SmoothingMode      = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
g.InterpolationMode  = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

g.DrawString(text, f, brush, 0, 0);
```

After reading some of the other posts about the same issue I tried clearing with the colour white, didn't change anything, then I tried adding a bunch of graphics settings like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038125/asp-net-textrenderer-drawtext-awful-text-images) said to and that only gave me

[image: wrong2]

Which has a bunch of unwanted black dots around it, which is arguably better then the first result but still not the crisp text I need, and clearing it with a single colour wont work because this text could potentially be on an image or something that moves

**EDIT:** i was able to get it slightly better with `TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`

[image]

Still isnt what i want but at least closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix it with the help of some people in the monogame discord by settings BlendState to `Nonpremultiplied` in the sprite batch where the text is drawn to

[image]